# What is the probability to pick a fraction that cannot be reduced?

Tags: probability

There are 14 cards numbered 2 to 15. If two cards are picked at random one by one, what is the probability that the fraction made from these two numbers could not be reduced?

---

Bruteforce:

$$
S_2=\{3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}-7\\ 
S_3=\{2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14\}-9\\
S_4=\{3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}-7\\ 
S_5=\{2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14\}-11\\
S_6=\{5,7,11,13\}-4\\
S_7=\{2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,15\}-12\\ 
S_8=\{3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}-7\\ 
S_9=\{2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14\}-9\\ 
S_{10}=\{3,7,9,11,13\}-5\\ 
S_{11}=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15\}-13\\
S_{12}=\{5,7,11,13\}-4\\ 
S_{13}=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15\}-13\\ 
S_{14}=\{3,5,9,11,13,15\}-6\\ 
S_{15}=\{2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}-7\\ 
\sum = 114\\
$$
So the answer is: $$\frac {114}{182} = \frac {57}{91}$$

---

**How it could be solved in other way?**

Comment: Picking "one by one" means with replacement, that the two numbers can repeat?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin numbers can't be repeated

Comment: The fraction can not be reduced if the two values are relatively prime. 
 Determine the number of relatively prime pairs of numbers between 2 and 15.  Divide this number by the number of ways to combine 2 out of 15 elements.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out by gd1035, the fraction can not be reduced if (and only if) the two values are relatively prime. So group the numbers according to the smallest prime which divides it:
$$S_2=\{2,4,\ldots, 14\}\\ S_3=\{3,9,15\}\\ S_5=\{5\}\\\vdots\\ S_{13}=\{13\}$$ Then the numbers are relatively prime if they are in different sets of this family.

Conclusion: there are $$7\times 3+ 4(7\times 1)+ 4(3\times 1)+ 3+ 2+ 1= 67$$ relatively prime pairs, giving the desired probability of $$\frac{67}{14\choose 2}=\frac{67}{91}$$

Comment: Don't you think the denominator should be $14\choose2$

Comment: Of course! Edited